# Quitting Node.js Program and Opening Another in Terminal

Tags: node.js

I'd like to have a condition in my current Node.js program where it will quit from occupying the command prompt and open another command line application instead.

What is the process that would accomplish this?

Comment: your running node.js process has no idea what a "command line" is. It's running on the cpu and is sending its stdout and stderr data to "Somewhere", which calling it through your command line interface means that command line interface. Can you explain why you need it to do this, so that we understand what you're trying to achieve, rather than how you think you should achieve that?

Comment: I wanted to make a Node program that would be the boot-up interface of a very simple linux box, to expose just a few very simple functions.  I was told that editing /etc/inittab was the way to change what the computer boots into, but I wanted to include an option for opening a normal BASH shell from this prompt to expose full functionality at times.

Comment: not sure that makes sense from an execution point of view. You could make it spawn a process, but it'll be "owned" by the node process so if that dies, your spawned processes die with it. The idea of running node as a boot-up interface sounds pretty weird, but then I don't have all the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is open another terminal, you can simply spawn a new terminal process.  Which terminal your particular linux distribution uses you will have to figure out, but for the purposes of answering here, I will use xterm.  You can spawn the process by the following command:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var oTerminalProcess = spawn("xterm", []);
```

Now you will pop open another terminal that should give you access to do whatever you need to do.  You can later on close the process with the following command:

```
oTerminalProcess.kill();
```

You will probably want to use spawn instead of exec because exec will have buffer overflow problems after the child process outputs > 200 kB (http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

Of course all of this assumes some sort of GUI desktop type environment.  If you wanted to do this all from a single console when a GUI isn't running, that's going to be a whole different problem.

If that is what you want to do you are going to have to attach event listeners to process stdin (http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin) and push directly to stdout and emulate a terminal yourself using exec.  This isn't terribly difficult, but I can imagine the details might get hairy for special cases.  It might look something like this (which I tested on node 0.8.21 and it was working for me):

```
var exec= require('child_process').exec;
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
var sInputBuffer = "";

process.stdout.write("$Prompt: ");

process.stdin.on('data', function(chunk) {
  sInputBuffer += chunk;
  if(chunk === "quit\n")
  { process.stdin.pause();
  }
  else
  {
      exec(sInputBuffer, function(error, stdout, stderr){
        if(stdout.length > 0)
        {  process.stdout.write(stdout);  }
        else
        {  process.stdout.write(stderr);  }

         sInputBuffer = "";
         process.stdout.write("\n$Prompt:");
      });
    }

});
```

Note I've got it setup for "quit" killing the program or in your case killing the stdin stream accepting input.  One problem you will have to overcome may be intercepting ctrl-c commands.  That right now kills the whole node, but you may want it to simply kill the command you were executing.  That will be some more work for sure but nothing you can't overcome.

At any rate, that should give you a couple of options to work with.  Hope this helps.

Comment: That does look right, (I'm using the latter scenario, no GUI involved).  I was wondering if I'd just be piping the child process into the current node process, and I agree this is a pretty managable solution.  Thanks for showing me your way, and pointing out the caveats of exec vs spawn!

Comment: I notice in your 2nd example you use exec instead of spawn, after you'd pointed out the 200kb max output on exec.  Could spawn be used for the same effect but without the output limit?

Comment: My asssumption when writing the 2nd example was that a single console command wouldn't overflow the 200 kB buffer.  However, i suppose you can't necessarily depend on that.  But you absolutely could use spawn and get around that limitation.  It would just be more difficult to know when to output the prompt again for more user input that way. . .